# Java Regex, Split String at punctuation marks except in brackets

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this String: "Hello, my Name is [[Peter.java]]."

The desired split is: [Hello, my, Name, is, [[Peter.java]]]

I split at punktuation marks but completly ignore things in these brackets.

I tried:

```
string.split("(?!\\[\\[.*\\]\\])\\s*(\\,|\\.|\\s)\\s*")
```

but this doesnt work because the output is [Hello, my, Name, is, [[Peter, java]]]. Can you help me?

Other examples:

```
"Hello. My name is [[Peter.java]]" --> [Hello, My, name, is, [[Peter.java]]]

"Hi. How, [[are,you]]" --> [Hi, How, [[are,you]]]
```

Comment: Does it need to be a regex? In your case it would be easier to do it another way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to split:

```
[.,\s]+(?!\w+])
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/hS1wF5/2)**

[image]

The **code**:

```
public void testRegex() {
    String str = "Hello. my Name is [[Peter.java]].";

    String[] arr = str.split("[.,\\s]+(?!\\w+])");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
// Output: [Hello, my, Name, is, [[Peter.java]]]
```

**Edit**: as **[HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401975/hamza)** pointed in his comment, the regex above fails is the string is `something, like this]`. So, to leverage the usage of **SKIP & FAIL** pcre feature, this regex can be improved by using:

```
\[\[.*?\]\]     # Match our brackets
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)  # Skip that match and proceed further
|               # or
[\s.,]+         # any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                         \f, and " "), '.', ',' (1 or more times)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/vX3uU3/2)**

Comment: Sadly I can't use this because String i posted was merely an example. I have to split at every space/punctuation mark exept if it is in these brackets. For example "Hello. I [[am.Peter]]." -->[Hello, I, [[am.Peter]]]

Comment: @Fede splitting without PCRE/perl magic `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is a bad option here. Matching is better.

Comment: Hi @HamZa sorry, I'm not a pro on regex I just like trying to resolve regex problem, so can't see what's the problem. Can you point me what I am missing here?

Comment: @Fede Look the grammar/expression is just incorrect. "Match a dot, comma, whitespace if not followed by a word character and `]`". See it failing [here](http://regex101.com/r/vX3uU3/1) (notice the space doesn't match before the word "Fail"). The author wants to "split by a dot, comma, whitespace if not enclosed between brackets". In PCRE this could be achieved like [this](http://regex101.com/r/vX3uU3/2), notice how we matched and skipped what's between brackets. That's exact expression the OP wants "skip what's between brackets and match a whitespace, dot and comma".

Comment: This is a common pattern. The problem is that SKIP & FAIL is supported only in pcre/perl (so very few engines). What most OP´s don´t realise is that we could as well change the expression: Instead of splitting, we match! How about this ¨Match anything that´s between brackets or match anything that´s not a whitespace, dot and comma¨. It will look like [this](http://regex101.com/r/vX3uU3/3)

Comment: @HamZa excellent lesson, I didn't know how to use skip & fail. Do only php and perl support it? Btw, your link is a beautiful answer, can I add it to mine? On the other hand, I know that my regex doesn't cover all cases but it could help OP for his specific needs (well, that was his comment). Once again, thanks for teaching me that I knew the discard trick but this one is the right one. You rock.

Comment: @Fede Great, I don't mind if you add, copy, modify or even subtract from my comments. I actually encourage to do so, we're all here to learn :) On the note about the availability of skip & fail, I said it was supported by PCRE, note that PCRE is used in a lot of software some I can think of are php, Apache's mod_rewrite module, notepad++ and much more. You could even download and use PCRE in your own software. That said, I tend to first test those magic features if they actually exist/do work on the platform/tool I want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using String.split, you'll probably want to use a different sort of regex.

`/\[\[(.*?)\]\]|(\w+)\W/g`

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aU3qJ9/2)</kbd>

Then use a matcher to iterate through the matches.

Comment: [Close enough...](http://regex101.com/r/kS8qJ4/1), I recommend to stay consistent when writing code. This isn't some codegolf/obfuscating challenge. So you either use `\[{2}` and `\]{2}` or you use `\[\[` and `\]\]`.

Comment: Breaks if you add a close bracket inside the bracket sequence. http://regex101.com/r/cZ2eD5/1

Comment: Right, I tend to avoid `.*?` for several reasons. We might improve the performance by using a negative character class. Also it doesn't match a newline without the `s` modifier. The last reason might be a desired effect which is most of the times unclear in SO questions :)